# snmprealwalk() returning empty array

Tags: php, arrays, linux

I done a simple snmprealwalk to a machine and returned it's manufacturer name, it's all good and games on windows, but when it comes to linux (lamp-server^ installed), this thing down here simply returns and empty array:

```
<?php

// error return
//error_reporting(0);ini_set('display_errors', 0);

$snmp = snmprealwalk("10.4.243.62","public", "iso.3.6.1.4.1.253.8.53.13.2.1.6.1.20.34");

foreach ($snmp as $key => $value) {
    echo $key . " " . $value . "<br/>";
}

?>
```

I tried to var_dump the $snmp array in the linux server and what i get is an empty array

```
array(0) { }
```

My questions are, why is this happening, how can i fix it?

Comment: If you don't specify the object ID you should get all objects back, and then you should be able to confirm whether this exists or not. That said, I don't have enough SNMP experience to help you further.

Comment: What you say is true, "" returns all the oids and respective values indeed but it sucks that i'm not being able to return a specific oid with this function :( it works flawlessly on windows *sigh* i'm tired of wasting hours making linux work for what ever the purpose ...

Comment: Can you see if the object ID is correct when you fetch all of them? Is there a value for `iso.3.6.1.4.1.253.8.53.13.2.1.6.1.20.34`?

Comment: yes, and i have copy pasted the first one just for testing and it just doesn't work(it does on windows with wamp), going to try this on another linux distro before going insane

Comment: If the key *is* there, then would it be possible to simply load all of them and only display that single key? (I know it sucks and that it's probably slow). Alternatively, if it *is* there then SNMP is working. Is there 3rd party PHP SNMP solution out there?

Answer (score 1):

After hours of braincrunching i finally found the culprit: **PHP 5.3**

When choosing to install the lamp stack **DO NOT USE** the **lamp-server^** package! (apt-get install lamp-server^). This will apparently install a deprecated version of php that requires php5-snmp.

Use this instead:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install apache2 mysql-server php5 php5-mysql
```

now snmprealwalk($ip,$community,$oid); returns array even when specific oid is entered!!

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out and thanks for updating your post!